# How can I create a Survey Form in Wordpress that users can fill in and then submit the entire survey contents as a post?

Tags: posts, forms

I've created a form using WPForms Lite that has a bunch of fields: Text fields, check boxes, radio buttons, more text fields etc....

I want to allow a website user (author) to complete the survey/review fields and then submit the form... which then automatically creates a post on my site.

All the plugins I've found with a "post form" just allow front end posting... They don't allow a proper "form" with 10+ fields to be submitted as a wordpress post.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I've tried the WPForms Pro, and it doesn't do it. I've tried Submissions by email, and then setting the WPForm to submit directly to that email address and it didn't work well.

Comment: Looks like I'm finally getting somewhere... i think I have to create a custom post type, then link the form fields somehow. Maybe WPForms and Gravity can both do this? I will not be generating any revenue from this site as it's more of a public service website. Are there any free plugins that perform this function?

Comment: You can use contact form 7 and there is post type extension for contact form 7 which will submit your survey form as a post.